# Is there a duplicate/copy paste function in Lego Mindstorms Ev3 programing?

Tags: ev3, programming

I remember, when I first started out Lego Mindstorms, there was a copy and paste (duplicate) blocks function. I could highlight and right click the blocks then press on duplicate to make another copy of it. This was extremely useful if I needed the robot to do something almost like another line of code, albeit with some minor changes. Is there something resembling this function now or did it never exist (my mind might be playing tricks on me)?

I am using the Lego Mindstorms Ev3 Student Edition by LabView.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember any context menu that pops up on right-click, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy highlighted blocks and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste them works.